# Animation on UIView in a for loop does not working?

Tags: objective-c

We have a for loop that perform animations on multiple buttons, with different delay.
What happens is that only some of the animations fired, and others are not. every time its another button that is not animating .

```
  for(UIButton *button in buttons)
    {
         int random=arc4random()%10;
        float time=0.5+ 1/(float)random;
        CGRect newframe=button.frame;
        newframe.origin.y=0;
        //nslog shows that all buttons are enumerated in the for loop
        //but some of them are not animated .

        [UIView transitionWithView:button
                          duration:time
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:^{
                           button.frame=newframe;
                        }
                        completion:nil];


    }
```

We have also tried :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:time
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                         animations:^
         {
```

Which will not work also .

Comment: If your for-loop would wait for the animation to finish then that would be a disaster for the responsiveness of your app. Grab a piece of paper and think it through. What is that code *really* doing when you add a loop to it.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist so you have another solution to create multiple animations, that starts together,and have a different delay ?

Comment: If you don't put `0.0` as the delay, you can use `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`. Just use a variable that you increase by some amount each time through the loop and use that as the delay.

Comment: this is not the solution for MY problem. i want to have a multiple views, that starts animation at the same time, but each has its own duration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to perform multiple animations at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23911304/trying-to-perform-multiple-animations-at-once)

Answer (score -1):

Found a great solution :

starting a timer :

```
 [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(open:)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:[buttons count]];
```

And 0.1 is much more than 0 in processor times, so now i can perform this on the timer method:

```
-(void)open:(NSTimer*)timer
{
    static int counter=0;

    int random=arc4random()%10;
    float time=0.5+ 1/(float)random;

    UIButton *button=[buttons objectAtIndex:counter];
    [UIView transitionWithView:button
                      duration:time
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                    animations:^
     {
         CGRect newframe=button.frame;
         newframe.origin.y=0;

         button.frame=newframe;
     }
                    completion:nil];



    counter++;
    if(counter==[buttons count])
        counter=0;
}
```

Which works great for anyone who need it .

Comment: I was looking for an old answer to a similar question but I couldn't find it. I'm also of the opinion that one can learn more by solving some problems themselves and that it's a useful exercise to break out small pieces of code, iterate quickly on it, look at the documentation, and refine the solution. In the end that helps one more than if someone else solves the problem and simply provides the solution.