# Trying to perform multiple animations at once

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

Seems strange that i could not find any answer for this all over the net, but seems that if you want  to move 6 `UIViews` at the same time in a different speed ,you can't do that.

If i am using one of this 2 example, i get that sometimes only some of the views are moving, and sometimes all of them (as expected)  .

There is no way to move 6-7-8 UIViews **at the same time** ,with **different duration**?

1.

```
for(UIButton *button in buttons)
{

    float r=   arc4random()%10;
    float t =0.1+ 1.0/r;
[UIView beginAnimations:@"Anim0" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:t];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionNone forView:button cache:YES];

CGRect newframe=button.frame;
newframe.origin.y=0;
button.frame=newframe;

[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

2.

```
 for(UIButton *button in buttons)
    {
         int random=arc4random()%10;
        float time=0.5+ 1/(float)random;
        CGRect newframe=button.frame;
        newframe.origin.y=0;
        [UIView transitionWithView:button
                          duration:time
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                        animations:^{
                           button.frame=newframe;
                        }
                        completion:nil];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to limit the random number generator.

Your function...

```
arc4random() % 10;
```

Will sometimes return 0.

Then passing this into...

```
float time = 0.5 + 1/random;
```

Will make `time = inf`.

You can see this by logging out the time values.

A time of inf will make the button not animate.

Comment: please, believe me, i am adding 1 to the arc4random() % 10; , and the problem still occurs. i am not lying .

Comment: and i am very sorry for being rude. you really just tried to help.

Comment: I have written a small project with 9 buttons and had the problem of some buttons not animating. But not all the time. When I logged the time this was the problem. Please show the exact code that is going wrong in your question. You shouldn't edit code before pasting into a question.

Comment: Also, I used the animation code that @Alladinian used for the animation as that is the correct way to animate views.

Comment: ok i will go and check everything from the beginning. thank you .

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible. The problem is that you're sending the wrong message. Based on your second snippet, this is an example of how it could be done:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.buttons) {

    int random        = (arc4random() % 10) + 1; // "+1" Added later in the answer, see Fogmeister's answer
    float time        = 0.5 + 1 / (float)random; 
    CGRect newframe   = button.frame;
    newframe.origin.y = 0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:time
                          delay:0.0f
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^{
                         button.frame = newframe;
                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         // The animation have finished
                     }];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried your code? try it, and you will see that what happens is exactly what i described in my question. don't be rush to think i didn't tried what you show here.

Comment: @Curnelious Have _you_ tried it? Because I certainly did before posting it... Thanks for the downvote btw

Comment: YES i have tried it just now, ITS NOT WORKING! Only few of them are moving and not all of them, even that i can see that the for loop is enumerate over all of them.

Comment: @Curnelious are you using AutoLayout? There isn't much to go on in the question and this is certainly the answer I would have given too.

Comment: @Curnelious also, don't shout. No one here is paid to answer questions. No one has to help. Shouting will just annoy people and then no one will help.

Comment: I am not shouting, but assume that if i spent 4 hours on this, at least you have to check your answer before you jump . run this, and you will see that every times one of the views is not animated, randomly.

Comment: @Curnelious using all CAPS makes it look like you're shouting. I'll have a go at trying this myself with a "minimal" project.

Comment: You should try that and also not use so much ego. I am working so hard on this and than you come here and comment like i am some kind of stupid. than your friend say "cheers". you guys are so not cool. don't help, i don't need that. i will work hard and find my way.

Comment: @Curnelious I get that it is frustrating when you've been trying to solve a problem for a long time. Do you not realise that we have all been there in the past? But there is absolutely zero point in being rude at the people who are trying to help.

Comment: When you will try that on UIButtons, and than see its not working always, comeback and erase your answer(if you can do that, or maybe your ego is too high).

Comment: @Curnelious Check this out https://www.dropbox.com/s/4xld66e26qm7ae7/Animations.mp4 (The same tested with 10 buttons)

Comment: @Curnelious Hah! I found your problem. Tell me... what is `1 / 0`? Try logging out the time before you run the animations.

Comment: @Curnelious Also, the issue where some of the buttons may not animate some times could be because of the random number generation

Comment: i have tried that also again a clean new project, and it happens again . and i don't get the 1/0 , because i have another line of code that adds 1 to the random.

Comment: @Alladinian yes, if the `arc4random() % 10` returns 0 then the time will be `inf` and so it won't animate.